# Nuget Multiple Platforms

Tags: windows-8, nuget

I need to package up dll via that is to be used in windows 8 metro.  Since there will be ARM devices as well as x86 and x64, do I need need to build a separate dll for each, or do can I just build it for "Any CPU?"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can build the dll with "Any CPU" and it should comfortably work with all the platforms, if you are still fuzzy about the bitness issues (x86 / x64), you can build seperate DLL's and package in one nuget package.

You can refer [Nuget Docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) for convenctions to publish the dll's for different profiles in a single package.

Cheers!